# delimiters and accents in WinEdt 8.1

Tags: symbols

I have just downloaded WinEdt 8.1.

In the toolbar I do not find  all the commands to type delimiters like
`{`,  that we use when typing latex commands?

I do not find the accents too.

Thank you

Comment: In winedt 8.0 you get them when you use view->tex gui symbols.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a shortcut to obtain the `pair` `{ }` and the cursor in the middle: open MainMenu.ini with the Options interface and find the `MENU="Shortcuts"`section. Add these lines at the beginning of this section:

```
ITEM="{ }"
  MACRO="[InsLabel('','{','}')]"
  SHORTCUT="32820::Alt+4"
  REQ_DOCUMENT=1
```

Moreover, if you select a piece of text, the same shortcut will put a pair of braces around it.

You can change the shortcut if it doesn't fit your keyboard: this one is interesting for my french keyboard, because "{" is obtained on the same key as "4", so for me it is "Alt+{" really. Just adapt it to a significant shortcut.

You can of course do the same for a pair of brackets.